# R avoid loops using builtin functions

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply

I am working in R language.

I have two arrays denoted E and y. E is indexed as E[state], and y as y[time,sample]. Thus, E is 1 dimensional, and y is 2 dimensional.

I have to calculate the following 3 dimensional array, denoted as P.

P(state,time,sample) = f(E(state),y[time,sample]), where f is some function. I wanted to do this without using loops.

Sample code is as follows.

```
# EM algorithm for HMM  
#y is array containing data
  T #length of time series
  nsamples #number of sequences observed
  nstates # no. of states in HMM
  P_forward<-array(0,dim=c(nstates,T,nsamples)) #forward probabilities in 
                                         #EM algo. for HMM
P_forward[state,time,sample] = 1/abs(E[state]-y[time,sample])
```

Comment: Without real data and some coding, this interesting question will not receive adequate attention...

Comment: Write `f` as a vectorized function; write your relations/"arrays" as tables; join the tables and compute your function with the columns.

Comment: @agerom . it seems there is no direct way to use apply() class of functions